# Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `img` must be a function (received `undefined`)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have just started my expo project, and whenever I try to use a component from a component library, I get hit with this error.

Right now, this is what my code looks like:

```
import FontAwesome from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { Link, Tabs } from 'expo-router';
import { Pressable, useColorScheme } from 'react-native';
import { Avatar } from 'antd';

import Colors from '../../constants/Colors';

/**
 * You can explore the built-in icon families and icons on the web at https://icons.expo.fyi/
 */
function TabBarIcon(props: {
  name: React.ComponentProps<typeof FontAwesome>['name'];
  color: string;
}) {
  return <FontAwesome size={28} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} {...props} />;
}

export default function TabLayout() {

  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'white',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#9695A6',
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#2D2B4D',
          borderTopStartRadius: 30,
          borderTopEndRadius: 30,
        }
      }}>
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          title: 'Hello, Kel',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'Roboto'
          },
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="home" color={color} />,
          headerRight: () => (
            <Link href="/modal" asChild>
              <Pressable>
                {({ pressed }) => (
                  <Avatar.Group>
                    <Avatar src="https://xsgames.co/randomusers/avatar.php?g=pixel&key=1" />
                  </Avatar.Group>
                )}
              </Pressable>
            </Link>
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

It gives me a render error. Any chance someone knows what's up? I feel it's related to the expo rather than the libraries or the way I import since I'm coping with documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the main problem comes from different environments of development.

- ReactJs: It's a library, and by using the renderer `ReactDOM`, you are working in the WEB area.
- React Native: It's a framework that uses ReactJs to develop the JavaScript side, and it will be registered on the Native side to create UI and functionality.

And now, by using `@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome`, `expo-router` and `react-native`, it means you are developing in the React Native world, and the web HTML, CSS, tags and some such haven't got any meaning at all.

**The `antd` is a UI web framework, and the `Avatar` component definitely uses `img` HTML tag, meaning it hasn't got any meaning in the React Native area.**

*It is the main reason you are getting undefined in the render.*

---

Suggestion: You should use some React Native UI library. for example: [rn-antd](https://rn.mobile.ant.design/)

Comment: You are 100% correct. I've been coding for a web for a few years and just picked up a personal project, that totally went over my head. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @RaquelCasadoDias No worries. It's a long journey. good luck.